# What should be a fragment in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know this probably looks like a silly question, but I'm finding fragments very confusing. I understand their purpose and how they can help to modularise code. They are appealing but all I've seen are very general examples of placing two fragments in one activity on a large screen and the same two in different activities on a small screen. I want to know how in practice they are generally used.

For instance the app I'm working on, and which is so far fragment-free, uses an inbox. I would like to convert my app into fragments but I don't know how to go about it: should the whole inbox be one fragment or should the listview be one fragment, the 'check all' bar be another, and the options bar when one is checked be yet another? At present I can achieve that look be just changing android:visibility to show and hide buttons according to events, but they look like they could be fragments and how they slide in and out of the screen on say Gmail, looks like it could be a fragment replace operation.

I just need to know whether fragments should be designed at a very general level of modularity - such as "inbox" - or at a more specific 'action' level. I'm sure it would be overkill to make every button or small group of buttons an individual fragment but where's the line?

Any help will be very much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easiest for those new to Fragments to think of them from a UI point of view.  There's a good image for demonstration in the [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

The goal is to make your app as flexible as possible for all devices.  To be able to deliver a great experience on a phone as well as on a tablet without having to write a tremendous amount of code.  If you have never worked with them, they can be challenging at first.  I would recommend creating a new Android app and use the template Master/Detail application as a guide.

As you put it: "a very general level of modularity" is how you want to conceptualize it.  Don't get too granular with it, like buttons and checkboxes.  Your inbox is a fragment, email content is a fragment, etc.

Comment: Hi there. I have no problem understanding fragments from the Master/Detail perspective - there they make perfect sense. It's just when there are additional but changeable UI components - such as in my case a delete button that pops up only if you have checked one or more items in the (master) listview - whether they should become fragments separate from the master.

Comment: I see.  I think that's up to you and your specific app's UI needs.  A delete button seems too granular for me, but that's just my two cents.

Comment: It's not just a delete button. Basically you've got one set of three buttons that pops up if you've ticked an item in your read or unread messages but if you're in the 'deleted items' section (ie the equivalent of a Windows recycle bin) you get a different set of buttons to restore or fully delete the item.

Comment: Gotcha.  Without seeing your app, have you considered moving your buttons into the ActionBar as contextual actions?  Otherwise, if the grouping of buttons is something you might want to present differently at a different screen size, then I think you should go with a Fragment wrapper around them.

Comment: Don't get me started on the actionbar. None of my computers are powerful enough to run the emulators so all I've got is a Gingerbread phone to test on so I can't use the actionbar. So I've been trying to make my own (as a fragment) - it works but it's not the real thing. As for your second point, I can't see any need for each individual bar of buttons to change appearance over different screen sizes but it's just that there are two of them and they can't both be showing at once.

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/ You can get the ActionBar on all API levels, thanks to this library.

Comment: Do I want to move this discussion to chat? it says. I think that means we've talked too much. So I think I should wrap it up. I'll mark yours as the correct answer or better yet you could delete my question if you have the privileges to do so cos it's a bit of a non-starter and I can't figure out how to word it properly. But thanks for your time, it's been a pleasure talking to you. I've already been considering actionbarsherlock but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A very abstract question. I well try to help you. Fragments were introduced to allow them to have business logic and ui together in one class for larger screens. So break fragments according to functionality. For small stuff use dialog fragments. The only logic that should be left in your activity isthe management of the fragments

Seems like inbox should be one fragment.

A good way is to think about your app on tablet and phone this way when you break screens, you can identify what can form a complete fragment. If you post more about your app. i can identify the fragments in your case

Comment: Hi. There isn't really much to say about my app, it's just a messaging app with an inbox, a read message screen (ie soon to be detail fragment), and various options to delete, star, and sort messages in the inbox via a bar fixed above them but which changes in appearance according to events in the listview. Just wanted to know whether that pseudo actionbar should be a separate fragment since it does change appearance at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Well though, from a design perspective in using an inbox, you might have **Fragment A** that is a collection of buttons used to select the message inside your inbox. Then You could have Fragment b, a collection of a header and the message body. Then when you click **Fragment A**, it updates **Fragment B**.
This would be at the more specific action level. IMO, a group of buttons being a Fragment isn't overkill. Every button being a fragment probably would be (: